# How to insert text in excel via vba

Tags: excel, vba

How to insert text = "here" in Z column if E column like "total"?

I try

```
Qtde = 50 'lines

For iLinha = 30 To Qtde
    compara = celula Like "*" & SearchString
    if compara then
        Orçamento.Cells(iLinha, 26).Value = "here"
    end if
Next iLinha
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is

`compara = celula Like "*" & SearchString`

You have not defined what is `celula`

Your code can be written as

```
Qtde = 50 'lines
SearchString = "Total"

For iLinha = 30 To Qtde
    If Orçamento.Cells(iLinha, 1) Like "*" & SearchString Then
        Orçamento.Cells(iLinha, 26).Value = "here"
    End If
Next iLinha
```

Comment: + 1 For actually addressing the problem in the question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood correctly, anyway:

```
Range("Z" & iLinha).Value = "here"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use VBA for that, simple functions can handle it!

```
=SEARCH("Total", A1)
```

This will look for the string "Total" in the cell A1.

If the value is found it returns the position in the string where it can be found.
If the value can't be found then it returns a `#VALUE!` error.

Therefore we can apply the `ISERROR()` function to check for these failures.

Couple this with an `IF()` statement and you get your answer!

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Total", A1)), "not here", "here")
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
for i=1 to 100 'assuming your goes in rows 1 to 100
    if InStr(1, cells(i,5).value, "Total", 1) then 
        cells(i,21).value ="here"
    end if
next
```